# Vector Field, Curl and Divergence. Simple computing and proving:

Tags: calculus

[image]

So I went through (a) and showed that curl( v x F) = 2v. (doing cross products twice, which comes out pretty simple.)

Now i am stuck at (b), it says use the results from part (a) to compute:
line integral <2,3,-4> x F * dr..

how should i do (b) and (c)?

Answer (score 1):

For (b), use Stokes's Theorem. What is $\text{curl}\,\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf n$?

For (c), look at various formulas you know about div and curl.

Answer (score 0):

(c) the curl of a vector field has no divergence, or $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \textbf{F})=\textbf{0}$